# Use posts from old db by changing prefix

Tags: posts, blog

I have moved a site from staging to production but now i'm missing the most recent posts, because while work was being done on the staging site some posts have been added on the production/old site.

The new site is using the staging db thats why i'm missing the posts from the production/old site.

Comment: You will need to manually add the missing posts from old live database to current live db. If you switch to old database for posts only you will lose all staging work settings and configurations so manually adding few missed posts in new database is much easier plan.

Comment: Wp Staging recommend using the old db for the new site, that's why. Isn't this a solution https://wordpress.org/support/article/tools-export-screen/ ?

Comment: Can't i use SQL to get all posts data to the db being used??

Comment: Still no solution for my problem.